# SOLR: What is the need for both query and filter query?

Tags: solr

With boolean expressions, the query parameter alone `q=...` can get the data you need. Alternatively with `q=*:*` the filter query fq could have the same parameters and achieve much of the same result.

I've always applied the second solution with `q=*:*` while having filter query "fq" for all, knowing that there is some filter query cache going on. So, why the need for both? Is always using fq for queries the correct way to go?

Comment: The cache should not be your concern when doing such decisions. There are [caches for nearly anything in Solr](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#Types_of_Caches_and_Example_Configuration). Also for Queries and QueryResults. Here is [another good write up](https://teaspoon-consulting.com/articles/solr-cache-tuning.html).

Comment: I'll have to disagree - you should consider how a filter query will impact a cache - in particular whether you should combine the filters into one fq or use several fq statements (as they're cached separetely). Being aware of the difference allows you to avoid trashing your cache, and might give a huge increase in performance.

Comment: That was not what I wanted to say. The decision to go for the fq or q parameter should not be based on whether there is a cache or not, but if it is the right thing. The initial query should be going to q, nearly always. Refining the results should go to fq ...

Answer (score 5):

`fq` will not affect the score of the documents - it's used to *filter* down the amount of documents returned by the query, not change the score of the document for the given query. `q` is what you're expected to use for your query, where scoring of each document's relevancy will be done.

The reason why you'd want to separate these - in addition to the filtering part - is that the cache for the filter query can be stored separately, meaning that you can cache the result of the filter, while still keeping the actual query variable. So if you're filtering for the value of `inStock`, that filter can be generated once and cached, while the actual query can change. Each document's 'membership' in the "inStock" result set does not have to be recalculated for each query, as it won't affect the score anyway - just an intersection with the already generated list of documents from the cache has to be performed.

[Common Query Parameters: fq](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) and [Common Query Parameters in the Community Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters#CommonQueryParameters-Thefq(FilterQuery)Parameter).